# How to remove duplicates from StringBuilder?

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to most effectively remove duplicate lines from a StringBuilder. Here is my code:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append("package autogenerated.dto;");
stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
stringBuilder.append("import java.math.BigDecimal;");
stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
stringBuilder.append("import java.sql.Timestamp;");
stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
stringBuilder.append("import java.math.BigDecimal;");
```

So after that I have the following String:

```
package autogenerated.dto;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
```

Could someone help me achieve something like that:

```
package autogenerated.dto;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
```

or that:

```
package autogenerated.dto;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
```

The order does not matter. Please be understanding. I'm not very good at Java.

Comment: Filter out the duplicates *before* you put the strings in the string builder (use a Set or something).

Comment: I'm not sure if I can because adding lines is done in a loop.

Comment: If your goal is to generate Java source code, a look at JavaPoet may be interesting for you.

Comment: thanks tquadrat, I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all the import strings to a `LinkedHashSet` (which will remove duplicate elements) and iterate over it afterward.

```
Set<String> imports = new LinkedHashSet<>();
imports.add("import java.math.BigDecimal;");
// ...
for(String str: imports){
   // add to StringBuilder
}
```

Comment: @KalEl Happy to help.

Comment: Note that this relies on the input Strings being full lines. If you allow adding parts of lines, e.g. "import java" followed by ".math.BigDecimal;", the Set won't guess that these two constitute a duplicate of the "import java.math.BigDecimal;" line. If you must handle line parts you'll want to wait for the whole String to be built, then split that into lines and unicize the lines before concatenating them back into a single String